# Правильная настройка .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, yii, yii2

Как правильно настроить `.htaccess`? В официальной документации для **Yii2**

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html

написано что так:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Но, если прочитать статью про `Options +FollowSymLinks` на

> Взлом сайтов через FollowSymLinks https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/90459/

то желание отпадает использовать Options +FollowSymLinks. Так как же все таки правильно настроить этот файл?

Comment: В чём конкретно состоит задача?

Comment: @Marat Tanalin в корневой веб директории , будет находится точка входа в веб-приложение, причем ко всем остальным файлам и дерикториям, кроме cs, js, img, доступ будет закрыт. Но не суть... Необходимо понять как правильно настроить .htaccess для yii2 , с Options +FollowSymLinks  или без него

Comment: достаточно написать `RewriteEngine on           

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f           
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d             

    RewriteRule . index.php`

Comment: Согласен с Алексеем, обычно достаточно 4-х последних строк (начиная с `RewriteEngine on` и заканчивая `RewriteRule . index.php`; у меня последняя строка обычно `RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]`).